# How to make a submit form talk to my php file to send an email

Tags: php, html, forms, sendmail

I am trying to get a website form to send to my email. The host has provided the Path to SendMail as:
**/usr/sbin/sendmail** but I am not sure where to put it. Below is the form HTML and the PHP that I currently have.

This is the form HTML that I have

```html
                <form class="email"  action="pages/mailer.php" method="post"> 
                    <div class="brown">
                    <h2>Request A FREE In-House Estimate</h2></div>
                          <div="boxy">      
                        <div class="row">
                          <p class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-4">               
                        
                         <label><span>Name</span>               
                        <input type="text" class="input_text" name="name" id="name"/>     </label>
                        
                        <label>                
                        <span>Email</span>                
                        <input type="text" class="input_text" name="email" id="email"/>     </label> 
                        
                        <label>                 
                        <span>Number</span>                 
                        <input type="text" class="input_text" name="subject" id="subject"/>     </label> 
                        
                        <label>                 
                        <span>Message</span>                 
                        <textarea class="message" name="message" id="message"></textarea>                
                        
                        <br/>
                        <input class="button" type="submit" value="Send" />
                       
                        
                        </label>
                        </div>
                        </div>
                        </form>
```

This is the PHP 'mailer.php' that lives in my pages folder.

```html
<?php
/* Set e-mail recipient */
$myemail = "personalemail@live.com";

/* Check all form inputs using check_input function */


/* If e-mail is not valid show error message */
if (!preg_match("/([\w\-]+\@[\w\-]+\.[\w\-]+)/", $email))
{
show_error("Invalid e-mail address");
}
/* Let's prepare the message for the e-mail */

$subject = "Someone has sent you a message";

$message = "

Someone has sent you a message using your contact form:

Name: $name
Email: $email
Subject: $subject

Message:
$message

";

/* Send the message using mail() function */
mail($myemail, $subject, $message);

/* Redirect visitor to the thank you page */
header('Location: ../index.html');
exit();

/* Functions we used */
function check_input($data, $problem='')
{
$data = trim($data);
$data = stripslashes($data);
$data = htmlspecialchars($data);
if ($problem && strlen($data) == 0)
{
show_error($problem);
}
return $data;
}

function show_error($myError)
{
?>
<html>
<body>

<p>Please correct the following error:</p>
<strong><?php echo $myError; ?></strong>
<p>Hit the back button and try again</p>

</body>
</html>
<?php
exit();
}
?>
```

Currently, when I hit submit the url changes to pages/mailer.php and I get an error

'Please correct the following error:

Invalid e-mail address
Hit the back button and try again'.

Any help is greatly appreciated!Thanks!

Comment: The PHP script never sets the `$email` variable.

Comment: You also never set `$name`.

Comment: And you don't set `$message` before including it as part of the new value of `$message`. You need to set all these variables from the corresponding `$_POST` variables.

Comment: And once you've done that, you should use `filter_var` to verify email addresses.